# Please ID leafy vine

Tags: identification

I saw this attractive climber in Cambridgeshire, England. Can anyone reveal what it is?

[image: My snapshot of mystery plant]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a Wisteria. If the photo was taken recently the normal flowering period (May-June) would be over which may explain why no flowers to aid identification. In addition it looks like this example is very green, which could indicate a vine with its roots close to a well-fertilized source like a lawn which receives a good dose of nitrogen.

Comment: It was definitely near well-kept lawns, nice observation.